# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference on Nullable type

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

So I searched through the other NullReferenceException and runtime binding questions on SO, but couldn't find an answer to this one.

Basically, I have the code below.  The method `ManipulateConcrete` returns False, as you would expect it to, but the method `Manipulate` throws

> 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null
>   reference

Code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myClassInstance = new MyClass() { MyGuid = null };

            ManipulateConcrete(myClassInstance);
            Manipulate(myClassInstance);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Manipulate(dynamic myClass)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myClass.MyGuid.HasValue);
        }

        static void ManipulateConcrete(MyClass myClass)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myClass.MyGuid.HasValue);
        }

    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public Guid? MyGuid;
    }
```

Am I missing something really obvious? Or is this a limitation of dynamic? If it's the latter, does anyone know the underlying reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `dynamic`, static types are not considered. So, inside `Manipulate`, the value of `myClass.MyGuid` is `null`, typed as `dynamic`. And `dynamic` does not know how to access any properties on a `null` instance, so it throws.

One way to fix this is to compare with `null`, instead of using `.HasValue`:

```
Console.WriteLine(myClass.MyGuid != null);
```

Another option would be to get rid of `dynamic` by casting to `Guid?`:

```
Guid? guid = myClass.MyGuid;

Console.WriteLine(guid.HasValue);
```

Comment: Yea, I noticed that != null works, but was wondering about the internal mechanism at play here. It seems to me that the cli knows that this is a Guid? (even though it's typed dynamic). Is there a reason that it doesn't do the cast automatically before trying to evaluate a property called on dynamic (this may be another question)

Comment: What makes you think it knows it's a `Guid`? It does not. `dynamic` is based on the runtime type of the value, except there is no value here, because the faux-`null` `Guid?` is boxed into a real-`null` `dynamic`.

Comment: When entering debug and setting a Watch on the the dynamic instance, VS is still able to determine that MyGuid is of type `System.Guid?`, and I assumed that this was available to the CLI as well (otherwise, where is VS getting that information?)

Comment: @Kolichikov Yes, the debugger knows that the type of `myClass` is `MyClass`, so it shows it to you like any other `MyClass` instance. You could get the same result by doing `MyClass myClassCasted = myClass;` and then using that, but that would very likely defeat the purpose of using `dynamic` in the first place.

Comment: Fair enough, though I'm still not quite sure why, if that information is available, the runtime can't figure out that the property is a `Guid?` (maybe they left it up to us to perform the cast only in situations where we'll need it?).  Anyway, that seems to be a different topic, and your answer helped me understand this portion. Thank you for explaining it!

Comment: There's a lot that the compiler does under the hood to make `dynamic` objects work, which can make it respond unpredictably if you don't know what it's doing. In this case, it is essentially creating a delegate object that represents each call you are making on `myClass`, so when it tries to bind one of those delegates to the object `MyGuid` and that object is null, it will throw. Run your .exe through ILSpy to see just how very different the compiled versions of your methods are.